# What does kafka streams groupBy does internally?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Let's say there's a topic in which chunks of different files are all mixed up represented by a tuple `(FileId, Chunk)`.

Chunks of a same file also can be a little out of order.

The task is to aggregate all files and store them into some store.

The number of files is unbound.

In pseudo stream DSL that might look like

```
topic('chunks')
    .groupByKey((fileId, chunk) -> fileId)
    .sortBy((fileId, chunk) -> chunk.offset)
    .aggregate((fileId, chunk) -> store.append(fileId, chunk));
```

I want to understand whether kafka streams can solve this efficiently.
Since the number of files is unbound how would kafka manage intermediate topics for groupBy operation? How many partitions will it use etc? Can't find this details in the docs.
Also let's say chunk has a flag that indicates EOF. How to indicate that specific group will no longer have any new data?

Comment: Note: groupByKey and groupBy are very different in kafka-streams. groupByKey doesn't introduce intermediate repartitioning topic, groupBy does. Here you meant groupBy, as you are changing the key.

Comment: I don't think the sort is possible. Maybe you should handle that in the way you aggregate the files, but I don't see what do you really expect as a result. Keep in mind that a streaming application is a non-ending app and that you can't sort an unbounded data structure...

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, you will indeed need some "EOF" information, or know the number of junks per file. Otherwise, there is not enough information when all chunks are received.

As mentioned by @Ayoub on the comment, there is no "sort" operation available though, hence, you would need to implement the sort manually. Also given that the number of chunks may vary, the best thing might actually be to not use the DSL but to implement a custom `Processor` with attached state store to give you full control.

```java
builder.stream("topic")
       .selectKey((fileId, chunk) -> fileId)
       .repartition()
       .process(...)
       .to("result-topic");
```

The `repartition` step would by default use the same number of partitions as the upstream input topic, but you can pass in a `Repartitioned` config object and set the number of partitions explicitly, too.

To add a state store to your `Processor`, you can overwrite `ConnectedStoreProvider#stores()` method in your `ProcessorSupplier`.

Inside the `Processor` you can just collect/sort file chunks as you which, and eventually delete from the state store after a file was re-assembled.